# Install operating system on one of existing partitions without affecting other partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, partitioning

My Windows 10 computer is showing the error "critical_process_died" and no Windows Recovery option is working and if I try to reinstall Windows 10 the Upgrade option(which let us keep files) is not working. In my PC which has a 1TB hard disk, I have three partitions, C(contains windows and important data), D(contains important data), E(contains useless data). I was wondering if it is possible to install a different OS like Ubuntu or Windows 7 into drive E without affecting other partitions of the hard drive? When the new OS is installed I'll get access to all the content on the hard drive and I can copy it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

[1] what i would do in this case is take a preferred Linux and install it on the "E" Drive. 
[2] then in the file manager of said Linux distribution it will list the partitions you mentioned and then you should be good to start backing up your data on an external drive.

hope that is more clear :)

linux should support and therefore "see" your partitions in it's file manager
https://askubuntu.com/questions/250736/how-do-i-access-files-on-my-windows-partition-from-ubuntu

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it [would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: just noticed that I also have 31.5GB unallocated space. Should I install Ubuntu on it?

Comment: As long as it's unallocated, then yes. I would do the same.